# Universal Windows - Cannot Debug new JS Project - wwahost.exe unable to find target registration

Tags: javascript, windows, uwp, visual-studio-2017, windows-10-universal

I am using Visual Studio 2017. I am running VS as an administrator, though this is not the same account logged into my machine (if that matters).

I opened a brand new project -- Javascript-language Universal Windows blank app.  I can confirm I am targeting the same version of Windows that I have on my local machine (build 15063).  When I try to debug the project with `Local Machine`, I get the following error:

> Unable to debug Windows Store app 'wwahost.exe'.
>
> The debugger was unable to find the registration for the target
>   application. If the problem persists, try uninstalling and then
>   reinstalling the application.

I've tried repair-installing VS, reinstalling VS, installing the Remote Tools for VS 2017, creating an app package, and nothing.  This is a brand new project.  The process `wwahost.exe` is not running on my machine; when I try to run it out of my Win\Sys32 folder, I get the following error:

> C:\Windows\System32\WWAHost.exe
>
> This application can only run in the context of an app container.

Not sure what to do next.  Please help.

---

Edit: So I'm running VS using an admin account, but it's not the same account with which I'm logged into my local machine.  If I log in as the admin account I'm using for VS, it works OK.  I want to be able to develop as a different user though.

Comment: Could you please try uninstalling the deployed app using the account, by which you created this project. And maybe also try create a new blank app using your current account, see if the problem persists

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Yes it looks like I cannot run VS as one account while logged into Windows as another. I guess that's just the way it is.